# How do I store a .Net MemorySteam value in DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, memorystream

I am using AWS KMS Encrypt API to encrypt a text. The Encrypt API returns a EncryptResponse object that has a MemoryStream attribute which is the encrypted value.

I am using the AWS .Net SDK and trying to save this value to DynamoDB.

How can I save this value? I tried converting this to a String but while the conversion saving DynamoDB and retrieval gave me back the MemoryStream object, the resultant cipher text from the recreated MemoryStream object cannot be decrypted with an error "Invalid ciphertext."

Here is the code used to save and retrieve the string

```
// convert stream to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ciphertextBlob);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd(); 

// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

When retrieving the stream it was noticed that the ciphertext was different for the object before saving and that during retrieval.

- [The EncryptFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=KeyManagementService/MKeyManagementServiceEncryptEncryptRequest.html)
- [The EncryptResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/KeyManagementService/TEncryptResponse.html)

Comment: "*does not work*" - **is not** (and never will be) a *technical description* of a problem

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do this, either (1) Convert your MemoryStream into a string and save that, all you need for that is to know the encoding, or (2) Save your MemoryStream directly as a blob to your DynamoDB (with `MemoryStream.ToArray()` to get the `byte[]`). But I can't say more without knowing more about your problem. Please [edit] your question and try and add more details

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks. This is what we ultimately ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by converting the memory stream object into a byte[] and saving it as a String in DynamoDB.

```
byte[] byteArray = ReadFully(ciphertextBlob);
                    string AccessKeycipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

The base64 encoding was used to get a String representation of the byte array.

The memory stream object was retrieved using the reverse.

```
byte[] temp_backToBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(AccessKey);
                 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(temp_backToBytes);
```